# Como se devem comportar os testes que manipulam a base de dados?

Tags: testes, testes-funcionais

No cotidiano nos deparamos com cenários em quais temos trechos de código que são executados uma única vez durante toda a vida útil do sistema. Como exemplo:

- Tela de cadastro do primeiro administrador.
- Tela de configurações iniciais do sistema (instalador).

Essas ações normalmente são feitas através de *middlewares*, as quais são executadas com objetivo de verificar se não há administrador ou configuração na base de dados, assim permitindo e redirecionando o usuário para tela de uso único.

Entrando na área de testes automatizados, como poderíamos testar esse tipo de comportamento único?

Dado, que na teoria, testes devem testar todas situações, devemos testar também esse primeiro acesso ao sistema, mesmo que o sistema já esteja em produção. Mas como esse teste deve ser efetuado?

Levando em conta que um teste deve entregar a base de dados no mesmo estado anterior a execução de teste, a solução seria rodar os testes em uma base de dados distinta da base usada de fato na aplicação? Usando essa prática não estaria criando testes 'viciados'?

Comment: O titulo fala sobre banco de dados (eu acho), mas ao ler a pergunta inteira parece que você esta falando de interface gráfica, por exemplo o teste atuar como humano para testar o comportamento passo-a-passo, acho que a pergunta esta um pouco confusa. É apenas uma *critica construtiva* para melhorara-la e deixa-la mais clara, assim conseguirá respostas mais rápidas e melhores =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado, mas não sei a confusão, eu citei exemplos de casos que o problema acontece, que são para fazer essas telas, no parágrafo abaixo da pergunta cito que essas ações usa o banco de dados para funcionar, logo o foco voltou ao banco.